# HTML CSS Text Aligned to image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate something like this:

[image]

So far my code is this one for HTML and CSS.

```css
.boxes {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    
   
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    
}

h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
}

footer .box1 img, footer .box2 img {
height: 8%;
width: 8%;
float: left;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-right: 35px;
}


footer .box1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    
    
}

footer .box2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
   
}
```

```html
<footer>
          <div class="boxes">
           <div class="box1">
      <img src="assets/cat.svg">
      <h2>Best in class features</h2>
      <p>Nobody does this stuff better than us. You can bet your life on that.</p>
           
           
               <img src="assets/swim.svg">
               <h2>An Acquired taste</h2>
      <p>It may take a little while for you to warm up to us but once you do you will never want to switch.</p>
           </div>
           <div class="box2">
            <img src="assets/world.svg">   
            <h2>Reliable Service</h2>
      <p>You can count on us to help you whenever you need it. We're talking around the clock service.</p>
           
           
              <img src="assets/columns.svg"> 
              <h2>No limits</h2>
      <p>They are absolutely no limits. We do not throttle. We do not cap.</p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </footer>
```

At this point I have no idea how to set the p and h2 close to each other and align them to the images. I already tried to modify padding and margin but it doesn't seem to be effective or at least i didn't find the right adjustments. Also it would be great if it could be responsive for when i resize the screen. Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: dont use float for styling purpose. It was mis-used out of it's actuall purpose and unfortuantly still is tought in so many tutorials. Use `flexbox` or `css-grid` which would be the actual right tools for it and being the modern styling solution.

Comment: I still didn't learn flexbox and css-grid that's why i'm still sticking with this method

Comment: is this for a school/university task? Unless so, I highly recommend to focus on `flexbox` and `css-grid`. It can be completly learned in 2-3 hours and will solve most of your stylign issues.

Comment: Yes at the moment only allowed to use these commands

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: flex` instead. See snippet and then from there you can style them how you like.

For further reference see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

```css
.boxes {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    
   
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    
}

h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
}

footer .box1 img, footer .box2 img {

margin-top: 30px;
margin-right: 35px;
}


footer .box1 {
    width: 40%;
    
    
}
```

```html
<footer>
          <div class="boxes">
           <div class="box1">
      <img src="assets/cat.svg">
      <h2>Best in class features</h2>
      <p>Nobody does this stuff better than us. You can bet your life on that.</p>
           
           
               <img src="assets/swim.svg">
               <h2>An Acquired taste</h2>
      <p>It may take a little while for you to warm up to us but once you do you will never want to switch.</p>
           </div>
           <div class="box2">
            <img src="assets/world.svg">   
            <h2>Reliable Service</h2>
      <p>You can count on us to help you whenever you need it. We're talking around the clock service.</p>
           
           
              <img src="assets/columns.svg"> 
              <h2>No limits</h2>
      <p>They are absolutely no limits. We do not throttle. We do not cap.</p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` to achieve it. It is simple and best. See code below:

```css
footer {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.boxes {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

footer .box img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="boxes">

    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Tn8DLxwuDMA">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Best in class features</h2>
        <p>Nobody does this stuff better than us. You can bet your life on that.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0F7GRXNOG7g">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>An Acquired taste</h2>
        <p>It may take a little while for you to warm up to us but once you do you will never want to switch.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/13ky5Ycf0ts">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Reliable Service</h2>
        <p>You can count on us to help you whenever you need it. We're talking around the clock service.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/X7UR0BDz-UY">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>No limits</h2>
        <p>They are absolutely no limits. We do not throttle. We do not cap.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

See it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/dyOMWJR?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know how can i achieve that without flexbox and css grid?

Answer (score 0):

without using flexbox/grid (and ignoring responsive functionality etc.) you could do it this way: 
Remove the `margin-right` from the image and add a `padding-left` to your h2 and p elements.
Maybe you have to adjust it a little, like u wish.

```css
.boxes {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: left;
}

footer .box1 img, footer .box2 img {
  height: 8%;
  width: 8%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

footer .box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

footer .box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

footer h2, footer p{
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1">
      <img src="assets/cat.svg">
      <h2>Best in class features</h2>
      <p>Nobody does this stuff better than us. You can bet your life on that.</p>

      <img src="assets/swim.svg">
      <h2>An Acquired taste</h2>
      <p>It may take a little while for you to warm up to us but once you do you will never want to switch.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <img src="assets/world.svg">
      <h2>Reliable Service</h2>
      <p>You can count on us to help you whenever you need it. We're talking around the clock service.</p>

      <img src="assets/columns.svg">
      <h2>No limits</h2>
      <p>They are absolutely no limits. We do not throttle. We do not cap.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```